# Move controls to the outer edges of a maximized form?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have been working on a windows form over the last couple days and I have hit a brick wall when trying to move my controls.

I think I have basic understanding of anchoring and docking but I'm not getting the results I'm hoping for so I have attached some screen shots of what I'm trying to do.

It's not about re-sizing more about moving the controls to the outer edges when my form is maximized.

Picture 1,

This is how it currently looks.

http://i45.tinypic.com/o73toj.jpg

Picture 2,

This is how it looks when I maximize my form.

http://i45.tinypic.com/ru9t2d.jpg

Picture 3,

This is what I'm trying to achieve.

http://i47.tinypic.com/28gxmoj.jpg

Comment: There's no evidence of you using the Anchor property in your screenshots.  Clearly you want to use the AnchorStyles.Right and turn off Left on controls that shouldn't stretch.  With a layout like that, only picture 2 really makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not to savvy on Windows Form's but looking at the documentation I found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx

With-in this class are properties like:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.right.aspx

I also found:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.aspx

which has the properties:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.width.aspx

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height.aspx

You could probably sort of "scale" the positions on your "components" (text fields, buttons, labels, ect.) by storing the original positions of your components, getting the 
height and width of the form, and moving them based on some ratio relative to that (if 
I'm making sense, if I'm not I hope you get the general idea of what I am trying to say).

Comment: Thank you, those links were very helpful